# How to automate the build number for iOS app based on Schema in Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, build

I would like to automate the build number of my iOS Application based on Schema we are building , like If it is Sandbox build I need to give as **{VersionNumber}S** and if it is Production build it will be **{VersionNumber}P**.
Can you guys suggest how could we achieve this in Jenkins Automation build

Comment: are you trying to change the way build number of jenkins basing on type of build ?

Comment: yes , basing on scheme would like to change build numbers